# How to immediately save within a Sequelize beforeCreate hook?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to hash a password before it's created and saved. However, when I have my hooked defined as below, I noticed that the log creates a guest instance with the original password and then immediately updates it. I'm not sure why.

```
// define model

const Guest = sequelize.define('guest', {
  email: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  password: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  }
});

Guest.beforeCreate(function(guest) {
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(error, salt) {
    if (error) { return error }
    bcrypt.hash(guest.password, salt, null, function(error, hash) {
      if (error) { return error }
      guest.password = hash;
      guest.save();
    })
  })
});
```

Here's where I actually create an instance in another file

```
//..

const email = req.body.email;
const password = req.body.password;

Guest.findOne({ where: { email: email }})
  .then(function(existingUser) {

    if (existingUser) {
      return res.status(422).send({ error: 'Email is already in use'})
    }

    Guest.create({
      email: email,
      password: password
    }).then(function(guest) {
      res.json({ token: tokenForGuest(guest) });
    });

  });
```

However, when I do this, it creates the instance with this password immediately (not creating with the provided password and then updating with that I've set):

```
Guest.beforeCreate(function(guest) {
     guest.password = 'TEST';
    });
```

Here's my server log that I'm getting:

```
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "email", "password", "createdAt", "updatedAt"
FROM "guests" AS "guest" WHERE "guest"."email" = 'mytestemail@example.com' LIMIT
 1;

Executing (default): INSERT INTO "guests" 
("id","email","password","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES 
(DEFAULT,'mytestemail@example.com','passwordsecret123','2016-06-26 16:26:54.683 
+00:00','2016-06-26 16:26:54.683 +00:00') RETURNING *;
::1 - - [26/Jun/2016:16:26:55 +0000] "POST /signup HTTP/1.1" 200 133 "-" 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
Gecko) Postman/4.2.2 Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Electron/0.36.2 Safari/537.36"

Executing (default): UPDATE "guests" SET 
"password"='$2a$10$VsU97hLMxZ76zGmNfJVlfOeXayyFbGMKK/EwE3SvKhOOEi9oAm9Qy',"updated
At"='2016-06-26 16:26:55.428 +00:00' WHERE "id" = 20
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
Guest.beforeCreate(function(guest, options, done) {
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
        if (err) return done(err);
        console.log('Salt: ' + 'getting ' + salt);
        bcrypt.hash(guest.password, salt, null, function(err, hash) {
            if (err) return done(err);

            console.log('Info: ' + 'getting ' + hash);

            guest.password = hash;

            console.log('Info: ' + 'password now is: ' + guest.password);

            return done(null,guest);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes!! Thank you. Looks like I missed the "return done(...)" part. Appreciate the help - spent hours trying to figure out why this was not working :)